# why I got empty database (no tables) when moving SQLite database file to another folder

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have an SQLite database file that contains 23 tables, when I moved the database file to another folder I found no tables!
how I can solve this problem?

note: I use SQLite with vb.net

Comment: Check your connectionstring. If it is incorrect then SQLite will create an empty database at the location set in the connectionstring

Comment: @Steve the connection string is correct 100%

Comment: Files don't magically change their content just because you move them. What you are saying happened didn't happen. As such, there's no actual problem reported here that we can help you with.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so do you think that I needed to waste my time just to put a joke!! I did the case much time and really when I moved it to another folder I found tables.

Comment: What I think is that you haven't actually investigated thoroughly and/or provided all the relevant information here so there's no actual problem for us to help with. What you claim happened didn't actually happen but you haven't explained what you did that made you think that it did happen, so we can't even tell you what you did wrong in that regard. Do a proper investigation and provide all the relevant information and then we have something to work with. For one thing, you should test multiple times to determine steps that we can follow to reproduce the issue. Where's that here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the File does not have extension .db so just I added the ".db" to the file